# Create Array of Generative Type in F# Type Provider

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm developing a library by F# Type Provider. I want to use a class with a field typed generated type array.I can define the field, but the constructor is failed.The code below is a part of constructor of class with a generate type field.

```
let expr = <@@ 
    (%%child :> Tree list)
    |> List.map (fun (t:Tree) -> getChild t)
    |> List.map (fun (ts:Tree list) 
                  -> (%%ctorExpr :> ConstructorInfo).Invoke([|ts|]))
    |> List.toArray
@@>
Expr.FieldSet(this, f, expr)
```

The type of field f is T(another generate type), but the type in expr is obj[] because it can't cast to generate type.I have tried some ways, but none dose not work.I want to change the inner type of array to generate type.How can I solve it?